# Show request header informations in Jetty inside SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, header, jetty

Does anyone have an information on how to enable request header logging (log4j2 configured over xml) inside Jetty in Spring Boot?

This didnt work:

```xml
<Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="SyslogInfoLogFile" />
</Logger>
```

Comment: Do you have slf4j-api and its layer to talk to log4j2 present in your classpath?

Comment: yes: slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar, log4j-api-2.7.jar            
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar
log4j-core-2.7.jar         
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar